# Terminal error Python git

Tags: git, python-3.x, terminal

I'm trying to update my Python version from 2.6 to 3.3 in terminal. Thus, I want to update the path as `PATH="~/usr/local/bin/python3"`. However, whenever I do this, I get the error

```
 git_prompt_info:1: command not found: git
```

Could someone please explain why this is happening/if I am going about updating python the right way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This replaces your `PATH`:

```
PATH="~/usr/local/bin/python3"
```

You probably want to *prepend* to it:

```
PATH="~/usr/local/bin/python3:$PATH"
```